# Ruby: is there a simple one liner for replacing part of a string between two indexes with another string?

Tags: ruby, string

Lets say I have:

```
a = "Stack Overflow"
```

Is there a function where I can do something like:

```
> a.replace!(3, 10, " hello ")
> a
=> "Sta hello flow"
```

or something similar?

basically, said function I don't know of would remove all text inbetween the specified indexes, then insert the given text after the start index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = "Stack Overflow"
a[3..9] = " hello "
a
```

Comment: Actually it needs to be `3..9` to get the exact output text you wanted

Comment: Or `a[3...10] = " hello "`, if you'd rather see the 3 and 10. "..." makes a range excluding the last number.

Comment: @glenn - nice, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

Untested code:

```
a[3,10] = "hello" ?
```

Comment: No, this replaces 10 characters starting at index 3.